# PETG layers are super rough

Tags: petg, layer-shifting

I own a spool of PETG and I have been having major print quality issues: layer offsets, chunks of 3D print strewn across the buildplate and other things. I traced these effects to a single culprit: rough layers. I don't know how to fix this. I haven't had this issue at all with any of my other PETG filament colors. And the buildplate height is just where it needs to be, so why is this happening?

#### Print settings

- Layer height: 0.23 mm
- Extruder: 235 °C
- Bed: 80 °C
- Retraction length: 6 mm
- Retraction extra restart length: 0.3 mm
- Z-Hop height: 0.25 mm
- Base print speed: 45 mm/s
- Extrusion ratio: 106 %

Comment: What slicer are you using? Do you have "combing" enabled?

Comment: I am using Flash print. I dont know where to find "combing in my print settings" @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE

Comment: Go a little warmer. Maybe 242. Also, that retraction number looks okay if you have a bowden setup, but it's way too high if you don't (1.5 is a better starting number)

Comment: Do you have a picture you could add?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably over extruding, this causes an excess amount of filament causing the mentioned problems. PETG is softer than PLA, so the extruder teeth grip deeper into the filament. This smaller diameter causes too much filament flow. Try to decrease the flow modifier for this spool of PETG.

Furthermore, your spool may have picked up some moisture, please dry the spool prior to use.

Answer (score 0):

Go a little warmer. Maybe 242.

Also, that 6 mm retraction number looks okay if you have a Bowden setup, but it's way too high if you don't (1.5 is a better starting number).

Finally, there are those who disagree on this point, but I only change my extrusion from the default 100% when I notice issues on specific prints. Ultimately, the extra 6% extruded material has to go *somewhere*, and it's likely contributing to the roughness.